# Rails 3 ActiveRecord group by child attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm looking to de-dupe a subscriber list, and have the thought that I should:

select all :subscriptions

join or include their :mailing_address

grouped by the mailing_address.name

having count > 1

I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax for this.

I'm trying variations on this:

`dupes = Subscription.joins(:mailing_address).group("mailing_address.name")`

but that gives me `Unknown column 'mailing_address.name'`

I've tried all sorts of variations but can't seem to figure it out...

and can't begin to know what the `.having` statement would look like.

Any thoughts or pointers would be immensely helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your child model is the class MailingAddress, then the conventional table name would be `mailing_addresses` (pluralized).

```
dupes = Subscription.joins(:mailing_address).group("mailing_addresses.name")
```

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't thought to pluralize. Also it looks like "mailing_address" and "shipping_address" both refer to a db table called "address" and so it's actually "addresses.name"!